# Why is Maven not including my file /src/main/resources/config.props?

Tags: java, maven

I thought that anything included in the `src/main/resources` directory would be packaged into a WAR?

I have the following structure:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/...
src/main/resources/config.props
```

The META-INF is included, but the `config.props` is not. How do i make this added to the WAR?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWAR</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Tell Maven what language version to use -->
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Enables the annotations, etc needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.exterprise</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Our jersey libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CDI to JAX-RS Binding -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish/jersey-gf-cdi-ban-custom-hk2-binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld/weld-core-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <!-- We don't use the version number in the file name -->
        <finalName>MyWAR</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <!-- Enhances the JPA classes -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>JPA Enhance</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>**/push/*.class</includes>
                            <excludes>**/com/*.class,**/controller/*.class,**/dao/*.class,**/dto/*.class,**/service/*.class,**/util/*.class</excludes>
                            <persistenceXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</persistenceXmlFile>
                            <toolProperties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>addDefaultConstructor</name>
                                    <value>false</value>
                                </property>
                                <property>
                                    <name>enforcePropertyRestrictions</name>
                                    <value>true</value>
                                </property>
                            </toolProperties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Where exactly did you search for the file `config.props`? It should be copied to the WAR under the directory `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose How can i make it copied to the root of the WAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of your WAR file is not resources, but rather `src/main/webapp`. If you want files directly under `WEB-INF` in your WAR file, put them in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF`. Resources under `src/main/resources` will end up under `/WEB-INF/classes` in your WAR file.

For example, if your source looks like this:

```
.
|____ src
|  |____ main
|  |  |____ resources
|  |  |  |____ config.props
|  |  |____ webapp
|  |  |  |____ WEB-INF
|  |  |  |  |_____ web.xml
|  |  |  |____ index.jsp
```

Your WAR file will look like this:

```
.
|____ WEB-INF
|  |____ classes
|  |  |____ config.props
|  |____ web.xml
|____ index.jsp
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, the content of the `src/main/resources` folder is copyied at the root of the classpath. That will be, for a standard WAR, in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, as Seelenvirtuose stated.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven Resources plugin documentation on  inclusion/exclusion (here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) is up front that some of your resources may not be included. You can review the documentation to make sure that you have identified any non-standard resources (for example, *.props is not a standard Java property file name) for inclusion.  You can also set the source and target folder if the defaults don't work for your project.